# Wordpress HomePage Problems

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After I migrated my wordpress from another host I found an incredible problem.
If Im logged in as admin on my wp site I see the homepage I set, if im loggin out I see a other homepage from previous theme and I cant replace it.

Here is screens to understand my problem:
https://prnt.sc/10enokq
https://prnt.sc/10enp7g

If im openning any other pages from site is all right
https://prnt.sc/10enrj0

Im really out of ideas ,

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the 'other theme' page is simply doesn't loaded the CSS. Can you doublecheck it?
(The print screens on itself cannot provide more information about the whole issue)

Comment: wordpress is loading the wrong homepage and css was deleted by in orderd to find a solution